# Adding Count Function

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010

Here are the tables we are working on.

```
HOTEL (HotelNo, HotelName, City)

ROOM_TYPE (RoomType, Descr, RoomRate)

ROOM (HotelNo, RoomNo, RoomType, PhoneExt)
FK1: Foreign key HotelNo references HOTEL
FK2: Foreign key RoomType references ROOM_TYPE
GUEST (GuestNo, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, State, ZipCode)
GUEST_PHONE (PhoneNumber, GuestNo, PhoneType)
FK: Foreign key GuestNo references GUEST

RESERVATION (ResNum, HotelNo, RoomNo, GuestNo, ArrivalDate, DepartureDate, NumPersons)
FK1: Foreign Key (HotelNo, RoomNo) references ROOM
FK2: Foreign Key GuestNo references GUEST
```

List the guests by name and the number of times each has reserved a room at one of our hotels. Arrange the list in order from most-frequent to least-frequent guest.

This is my SQL statement that retrieves all the names of the people who made reservations with the `GuestNo` appearing as well. I don't know where to incorporate the Count function.

```
SELECT GUEST.FirstName,  RESERVATION.GuestNo
FROM GUEST 
INNER JOIN RESERVATION ON GUEST.GuestNo = RESERVATION.GuestNo
ORDER BY GUEST.FirstName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for what you want, you need to use an aggregate function (Count) and also "Group By" which is what will give you the actual result.

I may be misunderstanding your example but based on the information I was able to glean, it should look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(RESERVATION.GuestNo), GUEST.FirstName, RESERVATION.GuestNo

FROM GUEST INNER JOIN RESERVATION on GUEST.GuestNo = RESERVATION.GuestNo

GROUP BY GUEST.FirstName
```

Edit: I think you want to group by guest, not Reservation #.

Comment: I've tried the group by part before. But your query gives me, You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'GuestNo' as part of an aggregate function.